# https on elb not working along with route 53 settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I'm new to aws. I'm trying to implement https with help of elb. I have configured ssl certificate on elb along with HTTPS(Secure HTTP) on port 443. I have also configured route 53 as shown in the snap shot. I have assigned elb to A-IPv4 Address. But still its not working for https, whenever I'm trying to hit https://www.mypleaks.com its not working but its its working for http://www.mypleaks.com, www.mypleaks.com, mypleaks.com.

[image]

Please find elb screen shots below:-

[image]

[image]

its showing:- 
[image]

Comment: By "not working" what do you mean exactly? It sounds like a configuration issue on the ELB, not Route53. Please provide more information about your ELB configuration.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have added 2 more screen shots, will you please have a look.? its not working for https means whenever I'm trying to hit https://www.mypleaks.com its not working but its its working for http://www.mypleaks.com, www.mypleaks.com, mypleaks.com.

Comment: Please expand on what you mean when you say it "doesn't work". Do you get an error in the browser? What is the error message exactly?

Comment: Sometime its saying page can't be displayed. sometime saying its taking too long to respond. And please don't mark it negative let me explain my problem and because of rating went I won't be able to ask genuine question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the Security Group assigned to your Elastic Load Balancer. I think you need to open port 443 in the Security Group.

Comment: Mark thank you so much it worked. but when I closed port 80(As I only wanted to connect my website only through https), it stopped working for www.mypleaks.com and mypleaks.com. Its showing connection has timed out. Do I need to update some configuration to redirect www.mypleaks.com and mypleaks.com to https..?

Comment: You should leave both ports open and configure your web server to redirect non https requests. You would do that in your Apache or Nginx configuration.